# How to add space between currency symbol and amount

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Net MVC in C# and need to add space between currency symbol and amount.

So far it is working perfectly well-displaying currency symbol attached to the amount but I want a space between currency symbol and amount.

it is displaying something like:  **£268,200.00**

but I want something like:         **£ 268,200.00**

```
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
                    <h3 class="label-bold"> @string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}", Model.totalPriceValue)</h3>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please note that what you ant to do is considered a typography error, in English at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [CurrencyPositivePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo_CurrencyPositivePattern) to get your desire output like following

```
var nfi = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( "en-GB", false ).NumberFormat;   
nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern = 2;
var a = string.Format(nfi, "{0:C}", 112.236677);

// Output will be £ 112.24
```